# FeatureDetectors not in OpenCV 3.0.0?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use the OpenCV `FeatureDetector` classes; MSER, Good Features to Track, FAST, etc.

But when I use them I get the compiler error:

> Error 1   error C2259: 'cv::FastFeatureDetector' : cannot instantiate abstract class

Do I need to include a specific header file, dll or something? Whats going wrong? I am getting compiler errors for pretty much every `FeatureDescriptor` I try to use. For example using `GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector` causes another compiler error:

> Error 1   error C2039: 'GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector' : is not a member of 'cv'

I am using OpenCV 3.0.0. I'm on Windows 8.1 using VS2013. I am including the following OpenCV libraries:

> - opencv_world300d.lib
> - opencv_highgui300d.lib
> - opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib
> - opencv_text300d.lib
> - opencv_features2d300d.lib
> - opencv_imgproc300d.lib

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"

using namespace cv;

void featureDetectorExperimentation()
{
    image = imread("i.jpg");

    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> fast = new FastFeatureDetector(40); 
    // Above line compiler error: "Error    1   error C2259: 'cv::FastFeatureDetector' : cannot instantiate abstract class"

    fast->detect(image, keypoints);

    drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, image, Scalar(255, 255, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_OVER_OUTIMG);

    imshow("Image", image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that the class you are trying to instantiate is [abstract](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class) which basically means that you can only use objects of classes that inherit from it, not the class itself.

In this case, you do not really care what exact implementation you are going to be using, thus you can use a pointer to object of type `FastFeatureDetector`. This pointer can be created for you by the opencv api with [`FastFeatureDetector::create`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/df/d74/classcv_1_1FastFeatureDetector.html#adf10eab3b23110c022183d098ae47023) function like so:

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> fast = FastFeatureDetector::create(40);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same error message. The error disappears when you do the following:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FastFeatureDetector> fast = cv::FastFeatureDetector::create(40);
```